# jQuery - Added Input will not allow me to add text

Tags: javascript, jquery

After I create an input it will not allow me to add text. I am working on a project that allows the user to edit their text by clicking on the added text to make a changes.

**[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/Stakeley/pen/VmjyVR)**

```
    var $input = $("#change");
var $btn = $("#add");
var $btne = $("#edit");
var $content = $("#content");
$btne.hide();


$btn.click( function(){

 var typedInfo = document.getElementById("change").value;
 var item = $('<li></li>');
 item.append(typedInfo);
 $content.append(item);


 $content.on("click","li", function(){
  });

 item.click( function(){
     $btne.show();
     item.text(" ");
     var typeNew = $('<input type="text" id="newInput" value = "edit">')
     item.append(typeNew);
       $btne.click( function(){
        var editedInput = document.getElementById("newInput").value;
        item.text(editedInput);
        $btne.hide();
   });
 });


});
```

Comment: Check this example works with multiple edited elements http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLMyXy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may be know, when you click on an element, the click event is propagated to the top of the document.

So, when you click on a new input, the click is propagated to his parent `<li>` and the `item.click(function(){...})` is called once again and the code is an other time executed and it rebuild all the current input area.

You have to stop the `click` event propagation to his parents.

```
typeNew.click( function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The full code

```
item.click(function(){
  $btne.show();
  item.text(" ");
  var typeNew = $('<input type="text" id="newInput" value = "edit">')
  item.append(typeNew);
  // Click on the new input
  typeNew.click( function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  // Click on button
  $btne.click( function(){
    var editedInput = document.getElementById("newInput").value;
    item.text(editedInput);
    $btne.hide();
  });
});
```

[stopPropagation documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 1):

`item.click` are in loop, always you click in item a new input is created. You can check for only [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) click with JQuery:

```
$("some_selector").one("click",function);
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you